# Link objects from polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I have 2 Models `Screen` and `Album`

```
# Screen
belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

# Album
has_many :screens, :as => :attachable
```

I've set up an album select on the Screen Form:

```
<% album_options = current_user.albums.map { |a| [a.title, "#{a.id}-Album"] } %>
<%= select :screen, :attachable_id, options_for_select(album_options) %>
```

Now i need to find the Screens who belong to a given album. I've tried a lot variations similar to this:

```
# Album Controller
@summoner = @album.user
@album_screens = @summoner.screens.where('attachable_id', params[:id])
```

But somehow every screen is shown in any album.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the where clause to

```
where(attachable_id: params[:id])
```